# E: Package 'honeyd' has no installation candidate

Tags: 14.04, apt

How can I install honeyd on Ubuntu14.04.
I get following Error when try to install it using  `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install honeyd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package honeyd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'honeyd' has no installation candidate
```

I also update my apt `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 2):

Honeyd is a bit dated, but it should still work...to build it, all you have to do is run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
wget http://www.honeyd.org/uploads/honeyd-1.5c.tar.gz && tar -xjf honeyd-1.5c.tar.gz
cd honeyd-1.5c
./configure --prefix=/opt/honeyd
make
sudo make install
```

Running honeyd seems to work in my copy of Ubuntu 12.04, and should work in 14.04.

Comment: I get following error while running `./configure --prefix=/opt/honeyd`:`checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for flex... no
checking for lex... no
checking for yywrap in -lfl... no
checking for yywrap in -ll... no
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for libpcap... no
configure: error: libpcap not found`

Comment: I think apt-get just work for: 12.04 :)

Comment: @academic.user You need to install the dependencies for honeyd. `make` is  failing because libpcap and the required headers are missing, either install libpcap-dev from the repositories or build libpcap from source.

Answer (score 1):

The package `honeyd` is quite old and not available in a PPA for your system.  You might be able to compile it from the sources available at http://www.honeyd.org/release.php, but you may find that this is a fair bit of work.

Comment: So, which open source honey pot do you recommend?

Comment: Sorry - got nothing for you.  The honeyd website above is about all I know about the project.